# ADR equation implicit solution: Penta-diagonal matrix for a 2D $N\times N$ system

Tags: finite-difference, matrix, advection-diffusion, implicit-methods

**Objective:** I am trying to simulate the following advection-diffusion-reaction equation in 2D space (x,y) and time. 
$$\begin{align}
\text{ADR Equation: }\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \nabla\left(v.C - D\nabla{C} \right)=  \alpha.C
\end{align}$$
I discretized the above ADR equation in 2D using finite-difference implicit scheme and as a result I get the following discretized equation.

$$\begin{align}
p_1C^{n+1}_{i,j-1}+p_2C^{n+1}_{i-1,j}+p_3C^{n+1}_{i,j}+p_4C^{n+1}_{i+1,j}+p_5C^{n+1}_{i,j+1} = C^{n}_{i,j}
\end{align}$$
where, $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5$ are constants in time.

I want to solve this as a system of equations using $A^{n+1}.C^{n+1}=C^{n}$, with no-flow i.e. $C=0$ outside the boundary domain. Here, $A^{n+1}$ would be a penta-diagonal, symmetric (not sure about this) and a diagonally dominant matrix. I have derived matrix $A$ for $2\times2$, $3\times3$ and $4\times4$ systems. For example, below you can see matrix $A$ for $3\times3$ and $4\times4$ systems, respectively.

**Issue:**

1. I am not sure if the form of matrix $A$ I have derived is correct because as per my understanding it should be symmetric, however, it's not as per my derivations.
2. Owing to an unsymmetric form of the matrix $A$ I need help to efficiently form $A$ for $N\times N$ system.

Would appreciate if someone could use their awesome numerical skills to answer these issues.

Comment: Doesn't pentagonal usually mean that the nonzero elements are in the shape of a pentagon inside the matrix? It's not common, so I'm not sure what you mean. The matrix would normally have nonzero diagonals $\{-n,-1,0,1,n\}$, like $T\otimes I+I\otimes T$ in terms of Kronecker product, but that's not pentagonal.

Comment: @Kirill: Please ignore the term pentagonal. But, matrix A that I am talking about looks like the one shown in eqn. 17 here http://geodynamics.usc.edu/~becker/teaching/557/problem_sets/problem_set_fd_2dheat.pdf

Comment: Or the A matrix for eqn. 6.4.45 in this link: http://www3.msiu.ru/~belova/compmod/Crank_nic.pdf

Comment: Or maybe the correct word is 'penta-diagonal'

Comment: It's not pentadiagonal either (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadiagonal_matrix). I would call this a block-tridiagonal matrix with tridiagonal blocks on the diagonal and diagonal blocks off the diagonal, but that's a bit awkward to say. Also, it's not going to be symmetric unless $p_2=p_3$, $p_4=-p_5$.

Comment: @Kirill: Parameters p1, p2,...p5 are shown in the attached snapshot and none of them are equal.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here. Based on your comments, you seem to have done everything right yourself.

Comment: @Kirill: I have edited the question to include the discretized equation in order of indexing and the corresponding coefficients. Please see if you understand the problem now.

Comment: @Pupil, You will not get symmetric matrix unless you use symmetric discretization  schemes for your convection term (eg Central difference, compact scheme etc.). In most of the practice we rarely use central schemes for convection because of its numerical dispersion nature .

Comment: @ArunGovindNeelanA: That's a pretty neat and clear reply to one of my question. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ArunGovindNeelanA: Can you answer one question in the context of this PDE? Question is: in case of heterogeneous medium where $v(x,y)$ and $D(x,y)$ are functions of spatial coordinates, do we deal that case  - $a)$ just by transmissibility terms which take the harmonic mean of adjacent grid blocks, or $b)$ by differentiating $\nabla v$ and $\nabla D$ in the PDE above since they are function of space, or $c)$ by incorporating both $a)$ and $b)$? Thanks

Comment: I prefer harmonic mean of $v$ and $D$ (to calculate "equivalent" $v$ and $D$ at interface), over mean, because it satisfy conservativeness. Since $v$ and $D$ are function of $x$ and $y$ we should discretize that too. My option is 'c'

Comment: @Pupil Its my bad, I answered your question without asking whether you are dealing with conservative form or non-conservative form in discretization. First up-all non-conservative form is not recommended for non-linear problem (heterogeneous medium) like this. I'm assuming you are using FVM or conservative form of FD method. Since $v$ and $D$ are user input. It is easy to define $v$ and $D$ mathematically as a function of $X$ and $y$. In reality this is not possible to define $v$ and $D$ exactly  as a continuous function of $x$ and $y$

Comment: So calculating equivalent $v$ and $D$ using H.M is good. If you are sure about distribution of $v$ and $D$ (only possible in mathematical problems) then no need to calculate equivalent $v$ and $D$. Since your equation is in conservative form your option $b)$ should like this $\nabla (vC)$. Please not that $\nabla$ here is difference operator  Then option $c$ is valid.

Comment: @ArunGovindNeelanA: Yes, it's $\nabla (vC)$, I just didn't write $C$ because it will be differentiated irrespective of whether $v$ is varying in space or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly just a matter of assigning an index to each vertex. If you have $n\times n$ unknowns $C_{i,j}$, $0\leq i,j\leq n-1$, then you would typically map the variable corresponding to the vertex $(i,j)$ to something like an index $I(i,j) = i + n j$. So each variable $C_{i,j}$ that is indexed by a pair of numbers $(i,j)$ is equivalent to the variable $C_{I(i,j)}$ indexed by a single number.

With this mapping, you rewrite the equations as
$$ p_1 C_{I(i,j)} + p_{2:3} C_{I(i\pm1,j)} + p_{4:5} C_{I(i,j\pm1)} = \cdots, $$

This means that the $I(i,j)$-th row (the $(i+jn)$-th row) of the matrix $A^{n+1}$ has the entries $p_{1,2,3,4,5}$ in columns $I(i,j)$, $I(i\pm1,j)$, $I(i,j\pm1)$.

With this indexing method the nonzero entries will all fall into the diagonals $\pm n$ (coefficients $p_4$, $p_5$), $\pm1$ ($p_2$, $p_3$), and $0$ ($p_1$). The main thing to bear in mind, when constructing such a matrix knowing its diagonal elements, is that the diagonal elements for non-existent boundary variables such as $I(i,n)$, $I(i,-1)$, $I(-1,j)$, $I(n,j)$ should be zeroed out.

So for a $3\times 3$ grid, you would get the matrix (I dropped the minus signs here)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 p_1 & p_2 & 0 & p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 p_3 & p_1 & p_2 & 0 & p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & p_3 & p_1 & 0 & 0 & p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 p_5 & 0 & 0 & p_1 & p_2 & 0 & p_4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & p_5 & 0 & p_3 & p_1 & p_2 & 0 & p_4 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & p_5 & 0 & p_3 & p_1 & 0 & 0 & p_4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & p_5 & 0 & 0 & p_1 & p_2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_5 & 0 & p_3 & p_1 & p_2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_5 & 0 & p_3 & p_1
\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kirill. One thing that concerns me is that this matrix doesn't looks symmetric. In fact, that was one reason I asked this question here because when I personally tried I was getting exactly this matrix, though in N X N domain.

Comment: @Pupil It has to be $n^2\times n^2$ because that's how many variables there are. It's not really going to be symmetric because the operator $\nabla\cdot (v C-D\nabla C)$ you're discretizing is itself not symmetric. I don't see how you can expect this matrix to be symmetric.

Comment: Yeah, the matrix will be N^2 X N^2, however, by domain I meant the extent of the studied area in X and Y domain, which would be N grids in X direction and N grids in Y direction.

Comment: @Pupil The general form of the matrix $A$ is straightforward, and is already explained in my answer. For constructing the matrix, one usually uses something like `spdiags`, or `diags` for specifying diagonal elements only. You can also just construct it by element-by-element.